# laravel app shows white blank page on Artisan cache:clear or config:clear command

Tags: laravel, web

My laravel app is working quite well but I noticed the mail config is not using the value from ENV so I ran artisan config:clear. Then, when I reload, the website shows a blank white page.

This are what I have tried so far but still not working:

- Check for whitespace in ENV value (found none)
- Run artisan config:cache, config:clear, view:clear, route:clear and even clear
- Delete cache files in bootstrap cache folder manually

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Please set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file and cache the values `php artisan config:cache`. Reload the page to check for errors. Alternatively, you can also look for error logs in the `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: Done but I got nothing. No clue at all.

Comment: 1- would you please share an screenshot of the black-white page? is it reporting a bug? is it blank page?  2- did you used any helper function in your config file? 3-  check your bootstrap and storage folders to have right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I have been able to solve it.

- My website was hosted on a shared hosting and I was running artisan command through route.
- Later I was able to use ssh access to run artisan command and turns out that it returns an error which prevent the command from running.
- The error was that each time I save and write value to env file, there was  a break line between my APPNAME.
- Since the artisan command didn't run when I hit the clear route, the cache config does not clear thereby returns the already cached data when trying to send mail.